# `Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` error while running `dotnet run` using a startup script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, startup, init-script, .net

I'm trying to run a dotnet app using `dotnet run --configuration Release` at system server Startup/Reboot. I'm using a `init.d` script to acheive the same.

My startup script, located at `/etc/init.d/myscript` contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/user/myscripts/botScript.sh
```

Contents of `botScript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/bot/
nohup dotnet run --configuration Release &
```

When my server Starts or Reboots the startup script gets executed but `dotnet run` doesn't work. I get the following error(s):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel.Resolution.PackageDependencyProvider.ResolvePackagesPath(String rootDirectory, GlobalSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.get_NuGetCachePath()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.NuGetCacheSentinel.Exists()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.ShouldPrimeNugetCache()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(INuGetCacheSentinel nugetCacheSentinel)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

But all other commands works fine in that script & even simply running `dotnet` works fine too (I have checked that). It's just that `dotnet run` doesn't work.

Yeah, but when I run the scripts, both `myscript` as well as `botScript.sh`, after loging in to my server, it works fine without any errors.

Please, can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: My completely speculative guess is that there's some dot-net "first time" configuration that's been done as your user account but not as root.

Comment: @JeffSchaller No. `dotnet run` works as root too. But not when I use that in a startup script.

Comment: There's an open ticket for this https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2385

Comment: @Artiom My user's home folder already has `.nuget/packages` folder. This didn't solved my issue. So, what do I do now? Should I copy/move some files there. I'm not that experienced in `dotnet`.